# Powershell / Sharepoint Audit logs, output a file for each user

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Im running a Powershell script that's returning selected Operations for all Users over a 24hr period. What I need it to output a .csv file **for each user**.

I have tried adding a For loop before $Audit which failed

````
$OutputFile = "c:\users\temp\downloads\unifiedlog.csv"
$Today = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date -Format “yyyy-MM-dd”)
$intDays = 1
For ($i=0; $i -le $intDays; $i++){
  For ($j=23; $j -ge 0; $j--){

    $StartDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j)
    $EndDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j + 1)
    $FileAccessOperations = @('FileAccessed', 'FileDownloaded', 'PageViewed', 'FileModified', 'FileUploaded', 'SharingSet') 

            $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -Operations $FileAccessOperations -ResultSize 5000 
            $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
            $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
            Write-Host $StartDate `t $Audit.Count
            }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I cannot test this myself, here's what you can do:

```
$OutputPath = "c:\users\temp\downloads"
$Today  = (Get-Date).Date   # a REAL DateTimeObject for midnight today, not a formatted string
$FileAccessOperations = 'FileAccessed', 'FileDownloaded', 'PageViewed', 'FileModified', 'FileUploaded', 'SharingSet'
$intDays = 1

# loop through the days and hours to collect audit data
$result = for ($days = 0; $days -le $intDays; $days++) {
    for ($hours = 23; $hours -ge 0; $hours--){
        $StartDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$days)).AddHours($hours)
        $EndDate   = ($Today.AddDays(-$days)).AddHours($hours + 1)

        $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -Operations $FileAccessOperations -ResultSize 5000 

        $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
        # output toget collected in $result
        $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent
        Write-Host "$StartDate `t $Audit.Count"
    }
}

# group the resulting data on the UserId property and output each group as separate csv.
$result | Group-Object UserId | ForEach-Object {
    $OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath ('Audit {0}.csv' -f $_.Name)
    $_.Group | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, Yes, that runs perfectly.  I need to upload these files to SharePoint and have added this code into the $results, 

        $destination = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx/Reports"

        $File =Get-ChildItem  "c:\xx\xx\downloads\"
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $webclient.Credentials = $psCred
        $webclient.UploadFile($destination + "/" + $File.Name, "PUT", $File.Name)  The error is "Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s)"  any ideas?